# Error handling with Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to retrieve a JSON object from my backend using Restangular.

1) This works great, but I don't know how I can handle errors because there is no callback/promise function :

```
meals = restAngular.all('meal').getList({date: selectedDate}).$object;
```

The following with the promises doesn't work :

```
restAngular.all('meal').getList({date: selectedDate}).then(function(newMeals){
    console.log(newMeals);
    meals = newMeals;
});
```

I got a Restangular object in my "newMeals" object instead of my Json object.
Something like :

> ```
> addRestangularMethod: function (){var g=arguments,h=a?u:this;
> all: function () { [native code] }
> allUrl: function () { [native code] }
> clone: function () { [native code] }
> customDELETE: function () { [native code] }
> etc..
> ```

How can I get my JSON "meals", using promises and being able to handle potential errors ?

2) Additional question : is Restangular still a good choice since Angularjs 1.2 and his better new $resource is implemented ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this:

```
restAngular.all('meal').getList({date: selectedDate}).then(function(newMeals){
    console.log(newMeals);
    meals = newMeals;
}, function(response) {
    console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**To get plain response object**

```
// using .plain() method
restAngular.all('meal').getList({date: selectedDate}).then(function(newMeals) {
    console.log(newMeals); // prints restangular object, ie, your response object with additional methods like get, post, put, remove, clone and many others

    // To get plain response
    meals = newMeals.plain();
    console.log(meals); // prints plain response object
})
.catch(function(response) {
    console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
});
```

**OTHERWISE**

```
// you can configure this globally in restangular config by adding below line of code 
// so that you will get plain response data by default
restAngular.setPlainByDefault(true);

// and now
restAngular.all('meal').getList({date: selectedDate}).then(function(newMeals) {
    console.log(newMeals); // prints plain object since setPlainByDefault is set to true in restangular config
    meals = newMeals;
})
.catch(function(response) {
    console.log("Error with status code", response.status);
});
```

Please see the [documentation](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) to learn more